# AWS EFS-IA and re-access to files where moved to EFS-IA

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-efs

I have a question about AWS EFS-IA storage (Amazon EFS Infrequent Access). Imagine that we set the lifecycle of access equal with 7 days, and after that 7 days, those files that have not been accessed will be moved to EFS-IA. What will happen if we access them after 7 days? Will they return back to standard EFS for next 7 days or will stay in EFS-IA?

I read AWS documentation and saw bunch of movies but they don't say any thing about after accessing to the file.

Answer (score 0):

The file restored from EFS-IA will move to EFS standard and stay there.

If the file was not accessed again for another 7 days per your lifecycle policy then it will go back to EFS-IA.

Answer (score 0):

Quote

> **Amazon EFS Intelligent-Tiering** offers an additional lifecycle policy
> that **moves files back** to **EFS Standard** or EFS One Zone automatically.

Source https://aws.amazon.com/efs/features/infrequent-access/#Save_up_to_92.25_on_file_storage

You use Amazon EFS Intelligent-Tiering what offer re-access files as normal.